# Combinatorial definition of the homotopy groups of a quasi category?

Tags: homotopy-theory, simplicial-stuff

The homotopy groups of a Kan complex are defined combinatorially, and they coincide with the homotopy groups of the geometric realization. For a general complex $X$, homotopy isn't an equivalence relation, so there are no combinatorial homotopy groups, and, as far as I know, one must define the homotopy groups as those of the geometric realization $|X|$, equivalently, as those of the (Kan) complex $S_{\bullet}(|X|)$. For my purpose this is impractical.

> Is there a combinatorial way to define the homotopy groups of a quasi category (i.e. a *weak* Kan complex) $X\;$?

The following surely is wishful thinking.

> Is there a (functorial) Kan complex $X'$ and a (natural) weak equivalence $X\xrightarrow{\,\sim\,} X'$ such that if $X$ is finite (in the sense that it only has a finite amount of nondegenerate simplices) then so is $X'\;$?

Comment: Why not refer to "weak Kan complexes" as quasicategories? In which case it becomes clear that defining the fundamental group will at least include the process of making a group out of a monoid.

Comment: @ZhenLin Could you expand on what becomes clear?

Comment: The fundamental group of a the nerve of a monoid is, if I'm not mistaken, precisely the group obtained by freely adjoining inverses.